# Character Constant error in hello world in Java

Tags: java

Please find the code below (m new to Java) :

```
public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println('Hello');

    }
}
```

Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid character constant

```
at Stack.main(Stack.java:7)
```

This is out of the blue for a simple program.

Comment: use `System.out.println("Hello");`, note that a String(more than one character should be between two `""` not between `''`)

Answer (score 5):

Replace :

```
System.out.println('Hello');
```

With

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use double quotes when printing out a string. The code below should run:

```
public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("Hello");

    }
}
```

If you were interested in printing out the characters that makeup the string "Hello", (i.e. print H, e, l, l, and o) you could do:

```
public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println('H' + 'e' + 'l' + 'l' + 'o');

    }
}
```

Again, this is because in Java, a pair of double quotes "" is used to denote a string, while a pair of single quotes '' is used to denote a character.

Answer (score 1):

A single quote is only for single characters i.e. Character Constants.

To use a String you need double quote.

Try

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

or

```
System.out.print('H');
System.out.print('e');
System.out.print('l');
System.out.print('l');
System.out.println('o');
```